# Obtaining a list of all classes used while running a Java application?

Tags: java, jvm

**What is the easiest way to obtain a list of all classes used while running a Java application?**

Assume that `com.package.Foo.main` is invoked by running:

```
java com.package.Foo
```

After running the program I'd like to have a list of all classes that have been used while running the program:

```
cat classes-used.txt
com.package.Foo
com.package.FooHelper
com.otherpackage.SomeClass
java.lang.String
java.util.List
java.util.ArrayList
```

In this context a class is defined as being used if it the class has been loaded by the class loader during program execution and the class' static block would have been run if such static block had existed.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432180/is-there-a-way-to-get-which-classes-a-classloader-has-loaded, although there's not much to look at

Comment: skaffman: I don't believe that it is an exact duplicate. My question is more general and well-defined.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run java with the flag **verbose:class**

```
java -verbose:class com.package.Foo
```

To append it to a file:

```
java -verbose:class com.package.Foo > classes-used.txt
```

etc.

It also list the jar where those files are defined:

For instance for this class

```
public class Test {
     public static void main( String [] args ) {
     }
}
```

I've got ( among others )

```
$ java -verbose:class Test 
[Opened /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/classes.jar]
[Opened /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/ui.jar]
[Opened /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/laf.jar]
[Opened /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/jsse.jar]
[Opened /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/jce.jar]
[Opened /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/charsets.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Object from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.io.Serializable from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.Comparable from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.CharSequence from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.String from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.GenericDeclaration from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.Type from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.Class from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.Cloneable from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.ClassLoader from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.System from shared objects file]
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick and precise answer! Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along these lines:

1) Enable verbose class loading by passing `-verbose:class` on your java command line

This will print a line like

```
[Loaded org.foo.Bar from file:XYZ.jar]
```

for each class loaded.

2) Post-process the output with the *nix text utilities (grep, sed, etc.) to find all instances of these messages and extract and sort the class names

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could also use [Jakarta Commons Discovery](http://commons.apache.org/discovery/), with code similar to the following:

```
ResourceNameIterator classes = new DiscoverClasses().findResourceClasses(Object.class);
while (classes.hasNext()) {
    String className = classes.nextResourceClass().getName();
    Class clazz = classes.nextResourceClass().loadClass();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in what methods are used, here is my method tracing tool:

https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/methodcallspy

You can also switch the tracing on and off, this way you can get trace of only selected functionality. You can filter out specific packages etc. The method `java -verbose:class` is not very useful with Spring applications, where nearly everything is initially loaded and initialized, but not necessary used.