# List all the classes used - compile time

Tags: java

Is there any way to make java compiler list all the classes used in the compiled source code?

For example, for code:

```
import foo.bar.Hello;
import java.util.List;

...

Hello hello = ...
String string = ...
List list = ...
```

I would like to get

```
java.lang.String
java.util.List
foo.bar.Hello
```

**Edit**

- I want it at compile time (or after compilation finishes), not runtime.

**Related**

- [Obtaining a list of all classes used while running a Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522329/obtaining-a-list-of-all-classes-used-while-running-a-java-application) is related, but it is about runtime, and I don't want to run the  program, just compile.
- [Java find out what imports a .class has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548765/java-find-out-what-imports-a-class-has)

Comment: [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: heard about reflection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtaining a list of all classes used while running a Java application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522329/obtaining-a-list-of-all-classes-used-while-running-a-java-application), although this obtains the information during the execution of the program, which may not be good enough

Comment: I think he wants DURING compilation, not running.

Answer (score 1):

During the compilation is not possible. You will have two choices close to the idea:

- use a program which print the imports after class compilation. You can write one using [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/index.html) for instance.
- if you're only interested by the annotation, you can try to add an annotation processor during compilation using [APT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html).

Answer (score 0):

Get all the declared fields. It will return you a `Field` array from where you can get your desired information about the fields such as field type, field name, filed modifier etc.

For more info read about [Field JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html)

Try this simple code

```
    Class<?> clazz = null;
    try {
        clazz = Class.forName("com.x.y.z.ClassName");

        for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            System.out.println(field.getName());
            System.out.println(field.getType());

        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```