# Java verbose class loading

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I am trying to list the order in which the Java class loader is loading my classes. if I use `-verbose` parameter it will list every single interface/class it loads, including tons of interfaces such as Serializable, exceptions etc. Is there a way to tweak this output so it only shows which classes are loaded in the class my main method is defined?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I guess your best bet is to do the following:

- Output some fixed text once your `main` method starts and right before it ends.
- Pipe the *verbose* output into a file
- Use things like *less* or *grep* to find the classes loaded between the two tags from the main method.

There's a similar question and some answers here: [Is there a way to get which classes a ClassLoader has loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432180/is-there-a-way-to-get-which-classes-a-classloader-has-loaded)

Did you try `-verbose:class`?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering where this is documented: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html

Answer (score 19):

Here's a sed expression that will parse the output of java -verbose:class to produce pairs of loaded class name and its jar file. You can further pipe through a sort to get unique jar files. For example,

```
java -verbose:class -version 2>/dev/null |
  sed -ne 's/\[Loaded \(.\+\) from \(.\+\)\]/\2/p' | 
  sort -u
```

outputs

```
/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/rt.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

For Java 9+ you can do it with `-Xlog:class+init`. E.g. this command prints the order of class loading when you start JVM:

```bash
java -Xlog:class+init -version
```

The command prints something like

```
[0.018s][info][class,init] 0 Initializing 'java/lang/Object'(no method) (0x0000000800000e60)
[0.018s][info][class,init] 1 Initializing 'java/lang/CharSequence'(no method) (0x0000000800009210)
[0.018s][info][class,init] 2 Initializing 'java/lang/String' (0x00000008000089b8)
[0.018s][info][class,init] 3 Initializing 'java/util/Comparator'(no method) (0x00000008000eb588)
[0.018s][info][class,init] 4 Initializing 'java/lang/String$CaseInsensitiveComparator'(no method) (0x000000080010dff8)
[0.018s][info][class,init] 5 Initializing 'java/lang/System' (0x0000000800002b68)
[0.019s][info][class,init] 6 Initializing 'java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement'(no method) (0x0000000800013cd0)
[0.019s][info][class,init] 7 Initializing 'java/lang/reflect/Type'(no method) (0x0000000800015210)
[0.019s][info][class,init] 8 Initializing 'java/lang/Class' (0x00000008000139e0)
```