# When classes are loaded?

Tags: java, class, loading

Well, I've got such a code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t; //1
        Integer i = new Integer(1); //2
        t = new Test(); //3
        System.out.println(Test4.a); //4
    }
}

class Test {
    private int a = 10;
    private Test2 t2; //5

    List<Test2> list = new ArrayList<Test2>() {
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                add(new Test2()); //6
            }
        }
    };
}

class Test2 extends Test3{
}

class Test3 {
}

class Test4 {
    public static final int a = 4;
}
```

I don't know how (fully or partially) and when classes are loaded. So:

1. `Test t;` - it is not an active usage, but the reference `t` must be a definite type of. Was Test class loaded (maybe partially, then how many stages - loading\linking\initializing - it passed) or nothing happened?
2. `Integer i = new Integer(1);` - was Integer loaded when JVM starts or on this line?
3. `t = new Test();` - an active usage. Was it loaded fully from the beginning or from some point (see 1)
4. `System.out.println(Test4.a);` - was `Test4` loaded or not?
5. Were `Test2` and `Test3` loaded or not? If yes then when?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When classes are loaded is covered by the [JLS, Section 12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1).

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).
> - T is a top level class (§7.6), and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.

(snip)

> A class or interface will not be initialized under any other circumstance.

[Chapter 5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5) talks about loading, linking, and initializing classes.

> The Java Virtual Machine dynamically loads, links and initializes classes and interfaces. Loading is the process of finding the binary representation of a class or interface type with a particular name and creating a class or interface from that binary representation. Linking is the process of taking a class or interface and combining it into the run-time state of the Java Virtual Machine so that it can be executed. Initialization of a class or interface consists of executing the class or interface initialization method  (§2.9).

Your questions:

1. Declaring a variable doesn't load the class.  But loading happens before linking, and linking happens before initialization.  So, when a class is loaded, it is also then linked and initialized.
2. The `Integer` class is loaded by the JVM (along with lots of other language foundation classes) before your code runs.
3. Now the `Test` class is loaded, because a new instance is created.
4. `Test4` was not loaded, because only a constant variable was used, which conflicts with the 4th rule above.
5. `Test3` and `Test2` were loaded after `Test` was loaded, because `Test2` objects were created in `Test`'s instance initializer, which also caused `Test3` (the superclass) to be loaded.

This is confirmed when [running your code with the JVM option `-verbose:class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230279/java-verbose-class-loading).

Comment: Noting that initializing isn't the same as loading (or linking).

Comment: If **Test** class isn't loaded at line (1) then what type will have variable **t**?

Comment: In the JVM, the variable `t` won't exist yet; it's not allocated yet.