# NoSuchMethodError for existing public method

Tags: java, exception, runtime

I'm facing a very mysterious `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` in the code pasted below. The same method, called through reflection, works as expected:

```
Widget a = getTextBoxWidget();
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject uio = a; // Widget extends UIObject
for (java.lang.reflect.Method method : uio.getClass().getMethods()) {
    if (method.getName().equals("getElement")) {
        System.err.println("Method " + method.getName() + ":" + 
                           method.getDeclaringClass().getName());
        System.err.println("Modifier " + 
                           java.lang.reflect.Modifier.toString(method.getModifiers()));
        System.err.println("Parameter count: " + method.getParameterCount());
        System.err.println("Parameter types: " + Arrays.asList(method.getParameterTypes()));
        System.err.println("Return type: " + method.getReturnType());
        try {
            Object result = method.invoke(uio, new Object[0]);
            System.err.println("Invocation successful: " + result);
            Object result2 = method.invoke(uio, new Object[0]);
            System.err.println("Invocation successful2: " + result2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to invoke getElement: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
// until here everything is good and it seems that 
// we can call getElement and get the result, but...
Object result3 = uio.getElement(); // line 470, here I get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
```

Output:

```
Method getElement:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject
Modifier public
Invocation successful: <result here>
Invocation successful2: <result here>
Parameter count: 0
Parameter types: []
Return type: class com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject.getElement()Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Element;
at com.pyx4j.widgets.client.ValueBoxBase.setAriaLabel(ValueBoxBase.java:470)
```

What can the possible cause for this?
`uio.getClass().getClassLoader()` is `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader, id=151`
`method.getDeclaringClass().getClassLoader()` is the same, with the same id.

Running with `-verbose:class` shows the `UIObject` class loaded from wherever it is expected to be loaded. The major version inside `UIObject.class` is 52, which matches the runtime major version (1.8)

Comment: @JimGarrison good catch, thank you, I mean `NoSuchMethodError` everywhere, fixed now.

Comment: `Object result = method.invoke(uio, new Object[0]);` This invoke method on object UIO and push parameter, maybe Try to use invoke without pushing params and lets look for the result?

Comment: @ThomasBanderas From the `invoke()` Javadoc: _If the number of formal parameters required by the underlying method is 0, the supplied args array may be of length 0 or null_

Comment: Is there a difference between `uio.getClass().getClassLoader()` and `method.getDeclaringClass().getClassLoader()`? Trying to understand if there are multiple class loaders in play here.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, try also printing the values returned by `method.getParameterCount()`, `...getParameterTypes()` and `...getReturnType()`.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki good question, `method.getClass().getClassLoader()` is null, because I assume the 'Method` class is from the bootstrap.

Comment: @khachik He meant `method.getDeclaringClass().getClassLoader()` to see if the method that's actually being invoked by reflection is in the same classloading hierarchy.

Comment: Maybe run with `-verbose:class` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10230391/1602555) and see what's going on with `UIObject` class.

Comment: @JimGarrison updated the question with parameter count, types and return type info. Everything is as expected.

Comment: Well, I'm stumped.  I hope someone answers.

Comment: @JimGarrison @KarolDowbecki `method.getDeclaringClass().getClassLoader()` is the same as for `uio`, with same id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the code actually might be different during the compilation and in runtime.

Reflection output suggests that `UIObject.getElement()` method return type is `com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element` however the JVM complains that it wants `com.google.gwt.user.client.Element`. Notice difference in the `dom` and `user` sub-packages in the middle of the fully qualified class name.

If there is no [covariant relation](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/covariant-return-types-in-java) between these two types, as in former extends latter, there might be an error. There is no type casting since line 470 is assigning to an `Object`. Maybe there will be a `ClassCastException` if an actual return type is used to declare `result3` in line 470.

Comment: You are a lifesaver Sir!