# Can `java -cp` report the jar or class file which it finds for each package imported in an executable class?

Tags: java, jar

When using `java -cp path1:path2:path3 SomeClass` to execute a class, is it possible to make `java` report the jar or class filename and pathname which it finds for each package imported in the class?

Comment: I believe you need to use the `-verbose` option, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230279/java-verbose-class-loading

Answer (score 1):

No ... and partly yes.

No because "importing" is a compile time concept only.  There is no need to `import` a class in order to use it, and an `import` statement doesn't actually mean that the class is actually used.   Also, you don't import a package: you import classes from a package, or static members from a class.

Partly yes because the `java -verbose:class` option will log each class that gets loaded by the JVM.

And if you want to statically find all of the other classes that are directly referenced by a given class it is possible to get this by analyzing the classes `.class` file.