# Deployment on wildfly fails with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, wildfly

When i deploy project on wildfly with `mvn install` occurs next exception:

> ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "webstore_war.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
>   {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"webstore_war.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
>       Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;"}}

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.packt</groupId>
<artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.t_systems.webstore_pack</groupId>
    <artifactId>webstore_pack</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <!-- Versions -->
    <springSecurity.version>5.1.5.RELEASE</springSecurity.version>
    <validationApi.version>2.0.1.Final</validationApi.version>
    <modelMapper.version>2.3.5</modelMapper.version>
    <spring.version>5.1.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <javax.annotation-api.version>1.3.2</javax.annotation-api.version>
    <junit.version>4.13-beta-3</junit.version>
    <postgresql.version>42.2.6</postgresql.version>
    <hibernate-entitymanager.version>5.4.3.Final</hibernate-entitymanager.version>
    <hibernateJpaApi.version>1.0.2.Final</hibernateJpaApi.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.8</lombok.version>
    <javax.servlet-api.version>4.0.1</javax.servlet-api.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>6.0.17.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    <commons-fileupload.version>1.4</commons-fileupload.version>
    <commons-io.version>2.6</commons-io.version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.9</jackson.version>
    <mockito.version>2.0.2-beta</mockito.version>
    <jms.version>5.1.9.RELEASE</jms.version>
    <activemq.version>5.15.9</activemq.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>webstore_war</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Dependencies>jdk.unsupported</Dependencies>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-fileupload.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernateJpaApi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-entitymanager.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.annotation-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springSecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springSecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springSecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${validationApi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>${modelMapper.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jms -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${jms.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>${activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: This may happen because your war ships with multiple versions of the org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils class. The class loader will only load one, and in your case it is the wrong one,

Comment: How can i check which class is loaded by class loader?

Comment: there is paramter ('verbose') which you have to set at startup of your vm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230279/java-verbose-class-loading

Comment: Check the artifact configuration, make sure it includes only one version of the jar file containing `org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils` class. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html.

Comment: @Andreas Hauschild Thank you very much. The problem was caused by org.apache.activemq.activemq-all dependency in which was ReflectionUtils class without accessibleConstructor method.