# Is there a way to find loaded class files in a JVM?

Tags: java, class, tomcat, runtime

This might be a silly question,but is there a way to find loaded classes in a JVM. Particularly classes that are loaded in to tomcat? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Are you trying to find out whether the class has been loaded by a specific class loader, or by any classloader within your JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use tools like [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) or [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) to see the usage of classes on your server. Another option that comes to my mind is to use [JVM Monitor](http://www.jvmmonitor.org/) plugin, if you're using Eclipse.

Comment: There are also [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) and [Java Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/index.html) which are distributed with the latest JDK. Look for jvisualvm.exe and jmc.exe on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you run java with the `-verbose:class` option, it will show what classes are being loaded - is that what you meant?

See also

- [How to Use Verbose Options in Java](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-use-verbose-options-java)
- [Is there a way to get which classes a ClassLoader has loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432180/is-there-a-way-to-get-which-classes-a-classloader-has-loaded)

Note also that the same classfile can be loaded into a single JVM by multiple classloaders; each one will be treated as a distinct class by the JVM.

Comment: I tried that command it only shows the classes relevant java itself. Not the user classes!.

Comment: What I need is; suppose there is a class "foo.baa.Foo.class" in one of my jar in WEB-INF/lib in a *.war file. When my application is up and running is there a way to find that "Foo" class in actually loaded to the JVM or not. Or in other mean list all the class files that are loaded in to JVM.

Comment: Ya! I'm trying to find a particulate class is loaded or not.