# Can we print more detail information than -verbose:class in hotspot JVM?

Tags: java, classloader

I used the VM options `-verbose:class`, however it just print the successed loaded class, like below:

```
[Loaded com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader$AnnotationCompleter from file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_71/lib/tools.jar]

[Loaded javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded com.sun.tools.javac.code.Flags from file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_71/lib/tools.jar]
```

however it didn't print the information when it failed to load the class, also it didn't print which class loader cannot get the class in a certain place.

what I needed is a similar options like IBM JVM options "-Dibm.cl.verbose" , which not only print the successful loaded file, but also print which class loader loaded the class, and which place it searched.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dclp1/index.html

I have no idea if hotspot have a similar VM options or other ways to print more detail loading information like `-Dibm.cl.verbose`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432180/is-there-a-way-to-get-which-classes-a-classloader-has-loaded ?

Comment: @RC, no , I already mentioned the option  -verbose:class,  however it print very limited information, what I needed is like the IBM  JVM options "-Dibm.cl.verbose"  in hotspot

Comment: In the linked question someone answered "-verbose"

Comment: The question linked by RC does not answer the specific question being asked here.  To my knowledge, there is no HotSpot equivalent to `-Dibm.cl.verbose`.